# Is there program that can do a dual screen random slideshow?

Tags: software-recommendation, multiple-monitors, slideshow

I've got a dual screen set up on my ubuntu machine and I'd quite like to set it up to do a random slideshow, with different images on each screen.  Is it possible to do this with one or more programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a single program that can do this but I have achieved the effect I wanted using a combination of two programs which I maximised in the two separate monitors.  The programs I used for this purpose were gwenview and geeqie.  To avoid the top unity bar being visible on one or both screens I did it in this order:

1. Make sure the two monitors displays are aligned side by side such that the mouse point leaves monitor 1 on the right and enters monitor 2 on the left.
2. Put the Gwenview window in the display of monitor 1
3. Put the Geeqie window in the display of monitor 2
4. Maximise Gwenview and start its slideshow
5. Maximise Geeqie and if the unity top bar still shows, turn off its slideshow (other wise you're done).
6. Minimise and maximise Geeqie with the slideshow off.  If the unity top bar is now gone, right click in the Geeqie window and start the slide show from the context menu.

You should now have two different slideshows happening, one in each monitor.

Comment: I should add, for consistency with the original question, that both these programs have settings to make their slideshows random.  Make sure you select those settings before starting the slideshow in each case.